# How to check webhook in sandbox for squareup payment gateway

Tags: api, curl, webhooks, square-connect

I am trying to implement webhook listener when a user make a payment using PHP CURL.
Here is my code

```
$ch = curl_init();
$data = array(
"[\"PAYMENT_UPDATED\"]",
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: Bearer sandbox-12346789899", "Content-type: application/json\r\n"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://connect.squareup.com/v1/my_sandbox-location_id/webhooks");
//return the transfer as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
// $output contains the output string
$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

But i am getting **Sandbox is not supported for Connect V1 API endpoints** error. Please help how i can test payment notification webhook using my sandbox account.

Answer (score 0):

Webhooks are under the domain of the V1 endpoints, so you will not be able to test them in sandbox at this time. You can test them with fake cash payments with your production credentials however.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can you tell me how to make fake cash payments with production credentials.

Comment: Use a mobile device signed into the same square account and then take a cash payment. It will trigger the webhooks because it is a production payment.